# jQuery: Creating an array from object data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

The problem is both the key and value variables are being set as objects. How do I convert these to a text string?

```
units = [];

$('thead th[style*="width:130px;line-height:1.2em;text-align:center"]').each(function() {

    key  = $(this).contents('')[4];
    value = $(this).contents('')[6];

    units[key] = value;

});
```

[JSBin of problem](http://jsbin.com/UCOFANi/1/edit)

Comment: What happened to `var`? Inline CSS in a selector?! Doesn't look right...

Comment: The selector works. See the JSBin. The problem is setting the key and value within the array. It set's it as an object.

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't work. But many things went wrong in so little code. You created a bunch of globals by omitting `var`, `contents('')` doesnt take any arguments, and inline CSS is a typical code smell, you should separate the styling from the logic from the markup.

Comment: I see. Well I'm trying to create an array like: [key: "value", newkey: "value"], instead when I run the console.log it returns an object. Any idea how I fix this?

Comment: Can you post the expected output? What are keys/values here?

Comment: console.log(units); ought to return: [key: "value", newkey: "newvalue", etc.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, the below is what you are looking for.

jQuery [.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) results a jQuery object. Hence you should `filter` only the text nodes from it and then get its `text`. (Note: I have used `.trim()` to clear out any extra spaces/line-breaks).

**jQuery:**

```
units = [];

$('thead th[style*="width:130px;line-height:1.2em;text-align:center"]').each(function () {
    key = $(this).contents().filter(function () {
        return this.nodeType === 3;
    }).eq(2).text().trim();
    value = $(this).contents().filter(function () {
        return this.nodeType === 3;
    }).eq(3).text().trim();
    units[key] = value;
});
//console.log(units);
```

**Console Output:**

> [pat (1" sq, 1/3" high): "5g", tbsp: "14.2g", cup: "227g", stick:
>   "113g"]

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/RntWc/)

**Note:** As others have pointed out already in comments, I wouldn't recommend using inline CSS in selector either. You could put them into a CSS class and then use the class in the selector like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/RntWc/1/).

Answer (score 0):

What are key-value exactly?  Can you use JSON way instead? Converting a JSON object will be cleaner and  easier using `JSON.stringify() method`.

```
var foo = {};
foo.bar = "new property";
foo.baz = 3;

var JSONfoo = JSON.stringify(foo);
```

Refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSON#JSON_in_Firefox_2) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help .

```
var units = [];

$('thead th[style*="width:130px;line-height:1.2em;text-align:center"]').each(function() {

    key  = $(this).text();
    console.log(key);
    value = $(this).contents('input[type=text]').val();
     console.log(value);
    units[key] = value;

});

for(var i in units){
  console.log(units[i]);
}
```